# Google Apps Marketplace SDK - Your input was invalid

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-marketplace

I'm having a hard time to configure an app on Google Apps Marketplace SDK. When I save, it keeps telling me that my input is invalid, but I don't know why. No indication about which field there is something wrong and why!

*EDIT*
I lost a lot of time trying to fill the form. I decided to give a try again using Firefox. 
This time, the fields are marked and a message indicate what is wrong. I try with Chrome and got the same issue. It seems that Google doesn't support his own browser!

Comment: For me the issue was: "At least one of Universal Navigation or Drive Extension needs to be enabled"